# Faild to load codeIgniter with bootstrap

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use bootstrap with codeIgniter but when I check the console in the browser I got this two errors:

http://localhost/mysite/css/bootstrap.min.css 
http://localhost/mysite/js/bootstrap.min.js

Am I missing something I have to do to lets the files load from folders not included in codeIgniter?

Comment: What errors did you get? Have you set your base url?

Comment: Yes I did.
Is there rule for folders in codeIgniter ?? seems cant find the right path

Comment: Did you try with index.php `http://localhost/mysite/index.php/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: what is the location of your js folder

Comment: Those URL's look quite standard, are you using .htaccess to remove the index.php? If so this might be preventing you from loading other resources. Add your .htaccess code to your post if you are using it.

Comment: I use .htaccess and JS folders inside view folder

Answer (score 0):

I think the path is looking for the wrong directory.

Try moving the css folder and js folder to the base directory.